# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un Ref y un Key en Google Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-datastore

Comencé a usar `Objectify` que es una librería para trabajar más cómodo con `Google Datastore` sobre el `Google App Engine` pero tengo una duda y es que no sé cuál es la diferencia entre usar `Ref` y `Key` en la definición de propiedades de mi entidad.

Por ejemplo:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    Long id;

    Key<User> driver;
}
```

o

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    Long id;

    Ref<User> driver;
}
```

Al parecer ambas generan una relación con la entidad User pero no entiendo cuál es la diferencia entre usar una u otra ya que al hacer consultas o insertar datos se comportan exactamente igual.

¿Alguien sabe cuál es la diferencia fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La única diferencia entre `Key <>` y `Ref <>`, es que la `Ref <>` es un contenedor que además de `Key <>` contiene una referencia a la entidad real. No sostiene referencias reales, el valor vendra de la entidad que se ha cargado previamente en la memoria caché de la sesión.

Con `Ref` y `Load`, es posible que tengas un menor número de llamadas a la base de datos; que depende de tu perfil de uso y la forma de sus datos.

Answer (score 0):

[ref](https://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html) es un wrapper, que incluye la clase [key](https://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/Key.html) y hace el llamado para cargar la entidad correspondiente, ya sea del cache o leyendo la base de datos.

En la mayoría de los casos es mas cómodo usar Ref

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24072300/142904) y [aquí](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/rbNMGyvs8qA) hay un par explicaciones muy detalladas de sus diferencias y el comportamiento de `Ref`